# Espresso 'is enabled' doesn't match the selected view

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm using Espresso 2 to test that a button is enabled or not. My code looks like this:

```
  onView(withId(R.id.fragment_vote_pause_btn)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
```

My button is defined as:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_vote_pause_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/audiowave_pause_or_play"
        android:textColor="@drawable/play_pause_button_selector"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Sometimes the test works but sometimes I get this exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is enabled' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is enabled
Got: "Button{id=2131296458, res-name=fragment_vote_pause_btn, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=329, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=false, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=375.0, y=649.0, text=Tap to play or pause, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:185)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at be.appfoundry.identify.ui.VoteActivityTest.test2PlayPauseButton(VoteActivityTest.java:39)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestResult.runProtected(DelegatingTestResult.java:90)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:49)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:63)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:270)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'is enabled' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is enabled
Got: "Button{id=2131296458, res-name=fragment_vote_pause_btn, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=329, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=false, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=375.0, y=649.0, text=Tap to play or pause, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:955)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$2.check(ViewAssertions.java:89)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that your button is not visible for the moment when you are checking  if it is enabled or not.

Could it be that are checking on window/button which is not activated yet? It could also be that operations are not synchronized and you have to wait for the resource to be enabled/displayed by using of idling resources.
The case could be:
1) the activity is not fully opened/loaded(adapter, etc.)
2) gestures are not completed fully(scroll,etc.)
3) after click on message boxes....
4) other situation when your button is blocked/not visible

Which one is your case? Have you seen on the device screen when it is failing?

This link also could be helpful -https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples

Comment: My button is visible from the beginning but it isn't enabled from the beginning.

Comment: As I understood it is visible but not enabled... Some action is enabling it and you would like to check if it is enabled or not. But error is showing that at the moment of your check it is with `visibility=INVISIBLE` &  `is-enabled=false`.  Have you synchronization with enabling operation?

Comment: You were right. In code the button was disabled in xml not.